# Serializing a Profile with associated Products with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm building a sample iOS app where users would buy and sell products, and I'm trying to design a page where the upper section will have basic profile details and the lower section will have the products that they're currently selling, something like this:

[Sample Frontend Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuW2P.png)

So I'm trying to create a Serializer / API endpoint which would give me the Profile, with the products that they are currently selling.

My Product model has a ForeignKey relationship to User:

```
class Product(models.Model):

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_seller")
category = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
(...)
```

And I have a Profile model which has a one-to-one relationship with the default Django user. As this view will be based on Profiles, I think it would make more sense to serialize the User or the Profile model and get the products where they are the "seller".

So the JSON response that I want is something like this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"username": “some username”,
"profile_image": "http://192.168.1.101:8000/images/profile_pictures/732339C5-E419-4A3D-9022-A314416F5F02.png",
"description": “Some description for this particular profile.”
“products”: [
    { “id”: 1,
      “image” = http://192.168.1.101:8000/images/abc.jpg,
    },
    { “id”: 2,
      “image” = http://192.168.1.101:8000/images/abc.jpg,
    },
    { “id”: 3,
      “image” = http://192.168.1.101:8000/images/abc.jpg,
    }
    ]
}
```

What would be the best way to approach this using django-rest-framework?

I've tried using Nested Serializers, but my User or Profile models don't explicitly have a relationship to Product, so they haven't worked so far:

```
class SellerProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta: 
        model = Product
        fields = ["id", "images"]

class SellerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    products = SellerProductsSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    profile_image = serializers.CharField(source="profile.profile_image")
    description = serializers.CharField(source="profile.description")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["id", "username", "profile_image", "description", "products"]
```

I've also tried using the SerializerMethodField, which I think would work in this case, but I haven't quite figured out how I would filter the products where the particular user is the seller. The endpoints look like this:

```
.../application/api/seller/1
```

If I could access the "1" - which is the user id, I could filter with something like:

```
class SellerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    products = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    profile_image = serializers.CharField(source="profile.profile_image")
    description = serializers.CharField(source="profile.description")

    class Meta: 
        model = User
        fields = ["id", "username", "profile_image", "description", "products"]

    def get_products(self):
        # get the id from the request / or the url  
        # filter the Product model.
```

I'm used to doing filtering on the viewsets, but not on the serializer itself. I think filtering on the viewset is not possible in this case, as I'm working with two different models and the one that I'm trying to filter is not the main model for the serializer.

I feel like there has to be a simple way to do this but I have been stuck for quite some time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want the ability to have a granular filter, then you better have a separate endpoint and fetch the user profile and products separately. Even if you want to return all associated products, it is a bad idea because they could be too many of them and you will need pagination to accurately handle them, which isn't very feasible in nested serializers. So the best thing here is to make 2 different requests for them

Comment: Yeah, I think that this is what I'll have to do in this case. I wanted to avoid multiple requests but in this case it seems like it will be the better choice. I hadn't thought of pagination, of course in most cases there would be too many products. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a user with pk in the url,and return a response with that particular user, and the result of the following query:

```
Product.objects.filter(seller_id=pk)
```

And add the results to a list,and return a response that looks like this:

```
Response({
  "Seller":Fetched User,
  "Their Products":list of products
})
```